# NetworkError: 414 Request-URI Too Large with Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My application create map using Google Maps v3 that have lots of markers and clusters on it, and it works fine.

Same map I have to show also in another browser window, but for some reason it can't (getting only empty map, without markers/clusters on it). I checked error in Firebug, and there is an message:

> NetworkError: 414 Request-URI Too Large

So - same maps, in first browser window is ok, in second it is not.

Just to say that I'm opening second map (in second window) by sending parameters about every marker I have on first map, so URL is very long (2700 characters).

Is there some way to solve this? Is it a problem with long url string?

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Yes I would imagine a "Request-URI Too Large" error is a problem with the long URL (...)

Comment: What I can do in this case? I need to send information about all of those markers to another browser window.

Comment: Try limit your request to 2000 characters by either removing some of the accuracy of the locations if they're not needed, or encoding them in some say (such as the algorithm noted at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm.html )

Comment: if request is 1500 characters still same error, if it is 1000 then there is no error. why first map works correctly? will help if i save parameters ie. in database on first window (map), and to read them when loading map in second window?

Comment: what browser are you using? ie has a very small limit 2k and a bit.

Comment: Firefox, but it's same with Chrome

Comment: The problem is in the URL generated by the Google API itself. There is nothing to do with your code or the browser. As suggested by jlivni, reducing the accuracy should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the URL you generated. Google specifies a limit of 2000 chars for the passed URL and we should stick with it.

I solved the problem in my application by generating a hash of the URL before passing it over to Google.

1) Create a database table to store your hashes. Columns can be hash, params, timestamp. You can improve your code by deleting hashes older than certain time, keeping the table small and fast.

2) Create a code (my_google_map_helper/get_hash) to generate the hash to be passed to Google and stick it somewhere. I am using PHP, so my code is:

```
// generate my hash
$hash = sha1(serialize($_GET));
// run an insert ignore into my hashes' table
// get the hash where the hash is $hash
// print my hash
```

3) Create a code (get_kml) to retrieve the params saved into the database from a given hash

```
if(isset($_GET['hash'])):
    // select params from my hash table where hash = $_GET['hash']
    // unserialize the saved params
    // generate and return my KML file
endif;
```

4) Change your JavaScript so it generates the hash before calling the Google function:

```
$.get('my_google_map_helper/get_hash?' + MY_LONG_PARAMS_LIST, true)
    , function(hash){
        Polygons = new google.maps.KmlLayer(
            {url:'http://my_url/get_kml?hash=' + hash , map:MAP}
        );
    }
);
```

Have fun!